# Paypal on Spree throws callback_url_is_wrong_type_you_must_use_the_https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paypal, nginx, spree

I am migrating Spree site from heroku to vps.

Site is working fine except for paypal_express payments. When final button is clicked and user should be directed to paypal page for payment I get:

```
Gateway Error: translation missing: en.callback_url_is_wrong_type_you_must_use_the_https
```

It was working fine on Heroku.

My nginx settings are:

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.slippers.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name *.matthewcookson.com matthewcookson.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri$is_args$args;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name matthewcookson.com en.matthewcookson.com fr.matthewcookson.com;


  ssl_certificate      /home/deployer/apps/slippers/shared/certs/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /home/deployer/apps/slippers/shared/certs/server.key;

  ssl_session_timeout  5m;

  ssl on;
  ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
  ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

  root /home/deployer/apps/slippers/current/public;


  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn; 
  }   

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10; 
}
```

I didn't change spree configuration

Comment: What's in your /config/locales/en.yml file?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/krzysztofbialek/9091871 . This error is thrown by some part of spree but I wasn't able to find it in repository.

Comment: Well I think either callback_url_is_wrong_type_you_must_use_the_https used to be defined in your locale file or it used to be in spree here:
https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/api/config/locales/en.yml

Maybe try updating Spree?

Comment: Upgrading spree isn't an option at this point. Question is what could change between heroku and vps that caused this error. It worked fine on heroku but stopped when I deployed it on nginx server.

Comment: Then add it to the locales file.

Comment: What's the point? Error is with https settings not the missing translation

Comment: Well you get Gateway Error translation missing.

Comment: translation missing is not an exception, just a message. I am looking for answer what is causing gateway to throw this error. And it's not missing translation, again.